# Package.appxmanifest: Identity-property and certificate (correlation?)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, certificate, windows-store

I'm confused. As with a lot of stuff with Microsoft development process regarding Windows Store Apps.

I'm soon going to submit my app to the Windows Store but I'm uncertain about the following in my `Package.appxmanifest` file.

```
<Identity Name="MyCompanyName.123456789" Publisher="CN=ABCABCAB-ABCA-ABCA-ABCA-ABCABCABCABC" Version="1.0.0.0"/>
```

This is obviously an example and something similar is created when using a a test-certificate.

On my Windows Store Dashboard I can find this Identity that I think I'm supposed to use:

[image]

In the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211441.aspx) it says what the "Publisher" property is used for:

> Describes the publisher information. The Publisher attribute **must
>   match the publisher subject information** of the certificate used to
>   sign a package.

What does this mean? "Must match the publisher subject information", what is that referring to? Since I need to create a real certificate soon, I need to know what stuff needs to match before I create it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're publishing through the store you don't need to worry about this. The store will sign the app.

Associate the app with the store from Visual Studio and it will set the Identity etc. for you. You don't need to do this manually.

You only need to handle signing if you're side-loading the app.